# How does tomcat make use of build.properties and build.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, build, web-applications

I'm following a tutorial to set up a skeleton application for tomcat :

http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring/setup#build_files

But I don't understand how build.properties and build.xml actually works.

I'm using windows XP and copied the following even though the required directory doesn't exist:

```
appserver.home=/usr/share/tomcat5.5
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/common/lib
```

Really confused now:(

Comment: If you don't mind, I have an entry in my blog to do this. http://requestandresponse.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/application-development-spring-mvc-source/ It basically contains the actual dummy project, I created a Build command that will automatically undeploy and deploy the application on the Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't use the `build.xml` and the `build.properties` files, these are for [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) which is a tool to automate the build of the application. The script shown in this tutorial is pretty basic, it defines 2 targets to compile sources and to clean compiled classes. And you would use them like this:

```
ant build
```

or

```
ant clean
```

The `appserver.lib` property is used to build the class path required to compile sources. It is derived from the root of your Tomcat installation directory and is used to find the JAR for the Servlet API that you need to compile sources. If you decide to use this Ant script, you should update the `appserver.home` property to match your install. For example:

```
appserver.home=c:/apps/tomcat5.5
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/common/lib
```

But to be honest, the whole setup is a bit messy (it's straightforward, but messy):

1. you shouldn't bundle the `servlet-api.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` as suggested
2. I don't like to develop directly under Tomcat's `webapp` directory (but this is maybe subjective).

Comment: Seems there is no `${appserver.home}/common/lib` in tomcat6 any more?

Comment: @symfony for Tomcat 6, use `${appserver.home}/lib` instead (this is where you'll find `servlet-api.jar`).

Comment: Is this why you said "1.you shouldn't bundle the servlet-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib "?Because it's already available for tomcat?

Comment: @symfony Because the specifications says so (the Servlet API jar is indeed provide by containers, Tomcat in your case).

Comment: Did you try spring mvc in eclipse?I found it's necessary to have servlet-api.jar in WEB-INF/lib,otherwise eclipse will report a Java Build Path Problem

Comment: @symfony Yes, servlet-api.jar has to be on the classpath during compilation but no, you shouldn't put it in WEB-INF/lib (other containers than Tomcat may complain about this spec violation).

Comment: Oh,got it.BTW,do you mean that tomcat isn't the only choice to server `.jsp`?